# Asignar una matriz al espacio de otra matriz c++

Tags: c++

Necesito igualar una matriz a un espacio de otra matriz "Mas grande" pero probando con el siguiente codigo

```
int main ()

{ 
 int Matriz [3][3],i,j;
 int SubMatriz [3][3],a,b;

    Matriz [0][0] = SubMatriz;
}
```

Trato de igualar el espacio 0,0 de la primera matriz a toda la submatriz, es decir que ese espacio de 1x1 se convierta en una matriz de 3x3, Que estoy haciendo mal? o si alguien sabe cual es la forma correcta de hacer estas igualaciones

Comment: alguien lo va a explicar mejor.. pero hay un error de concepto.. en la pos 0,0 hay espacio para un int (4 bytes) y submatriz si mal no recuerdo es un puntero..

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pretendes no es tan sencillo como te piensas. Si tu declararas una matriz tal que:

```
int matriz[3][3];
```

El compilador reserva 9 posiciones consecutivas en la pila para almacenar los 9 valores de la matriz. Así ante el siguiente código:

```
int matriz[3][3];
for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
{
  for( int j=0; j<3; j++ )
    matriz[i][j] = 3*(i*3+j)
}
```

Genera la siguiente secuencia en la memoria:

```
OFFSET: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08
VALOR:  00 03 06 09 12 15 18 21 24
```

Sin embargo si declaramos la matriz de forma dinámica:

```
int** matriz = new int*[3];
for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
  matriz[i] = new int[3];
```

El mapa de la memoria es diferente. En vez de ocupar 9 posiciones consecutivas en la memoria ahora tenemos un primer nivel compuesto por tres punteros y en cada una de esas posiciones apuntadas tenemos 3 valores. Es decir, al final tenemos los 9 valores que deseamos almacenar y tres punteros de propina.

¿Por qué te cuento este rollo?

Básicamente porque las matrices o vectores declarados en la pila son unos punteros con características especiales:

- no pueden ser reasignados
- su estructura interna es fija

En resumidas cuentas, para conseguir que un elemento de `Matriz` apunte a `SubMatriz` necesitas que `Matriz` sea una matriz de punteros... pero ya has visto que la estructura de un puntero es diferente a la de una matriz en la pila. ¿Cómo hacerlo entonces?

Se puede conseguir simular el uso pero no es demasiado bonito:

```
int SubMatriz[3][3];

int* Matriz[3][3][3];
for( int i=0;i<3;i++)
    Matriz[0][0][i] = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&SubMatriz[i]);
```

Comment: Creo que deberías revisar la parte de memoria dinámica.

Comment: @Mateo cierto ... en qué estaría pensando ... XD

Comment: Por cierto, en lugar de usar 2 niveles de indirección puedes usar uno solo con `new [9]`. En ese caso podrías *mapear* manualmente la memoria a una matriz o que el compilador lo haga por vos convirtiendo el puntero a `int(*)[3]`. O usar `new int[3][3]`.

Comment: @Mateo lo se, piensa que el ejercicio es de hace 6 años ... :)